# Trying to make a ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have tried to construct a ListView and i have made the following code...

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    StringAdapter nAdapter = new StringAdapter();
    ListView v = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView_01);
    v.setAdapter(nAdapter);
    setContentView(v);
}
```

i have constructed the following class..

```
public class StringAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private  ArrayList<String> items;
private  LayoutInflater mInflater;

public void StringAdapter(Context context){
    items = new ArrayList<String>();
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    for (int i=0 ; i < 3 ;  i++) {
        String addstring;
        addstring = "Item" + i;
        items.add(addstring);

    }
}
```

and the xml file is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<ListView
    android:id ="@+id/ListView_01"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />
```

The problem is that i cannot see anything on the screen..

Can somebody explain to me where is my fault and in general how ListView work ?

Comment: It doesn't look like you're doing anything with the 'items' variable after adding the items. Try putting the items into the list view.

Comment: you need to add your items to your adapter (getview). Anyway, you have a lot of articles explaining the listview and building custom adapters. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: this should not compile, as BaseAdapter is abstract and getView too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined a method called `StringAdapter(Context)`. Judging from the contents of this method, you probably wanted to create a constructor for your `StringAdapter` class instead.

Simply remove the return type (`void`) from this method signature, and that will become a constructor.